# How to create several Pandas dataframes and assign their names as elements from a list

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'entity': ['foo', ' bar', 'baz', 'buzz', 'bar', 'buzz', 'foo', 'foo'],
        'value': [4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 4]
    })
    
df


    entity  value
0   foo     4
1   bar     3
2   baz     2
3   buzz    1
4   bar     9
5   buzz    8
6   foo     7
7   foo     4
```

For each unique value of `entity`, I'd like to create a separate dataframe and assign its name as the unique value of `entity`, prefaced with `df_`:

For example:

```
df_foo
df_bar
df_baz
df_buzz
```

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: `out = dict(df.groupby('entity'))` or with prefix `out = {f'df_{k}': g for k, g in df.groupby('entity')}` (useless in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

Try use groupby and map function in pandas

```
df_dict = dict(map(lambda x: (f"df_{x[0].strip()}", x[1].reset_index(drop=True)),
                   df.groupby('entity'))
)

df_foo = df_dict.get('df_foo')
df_bar = df_dict.get('df_bar')
df_baz = df_dict.get('df_baz')
df_buzz = df_dict.get('df_buzz')
```

Comment: `out = dict(df.groupby('entity'))` is more than enough, then access the dictionary items by key

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I think it is a better way.

Comment: @mozway I get TypeError: 'str' object is not callable for out = dict(df.groupby('entity')) why? I think it should be fine

Comment: You likely have an old pandas (which version?), you can use `dict(list(df.groupby('entity')))`